# Interesting problem in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are $100$ students in a classroom. Let $a_i$ denote the number of friends of the $i^{th}$ student. Let $c_j$ denote the number of students having at least $j$ number of friends. Prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i = \sum_{j=1}^{99} c_j$$
I have a few doubts regarding the problem statement. Suppose $2$ is a friend of $1$, does that necessarily mean $1$ is a friend of $2$? Will $c_0$ be always $100$, or rather what does having at least $0$ friends mean?

Comment: Being friends is a symmetric relation, so if $1$ is a friend of $2$ then $2$ is a friend of $1$. Note that $a_i$ is the number of friends of the student $i$, it is not the student itself as you wrote. About your second question: yes $c_0=100$, that is, every student has at least $0$ friends.

Comment: Ok instead of 100 consider 3. Then this relation will not hold for a simple test case.

Comment: you are right, as the counterexample in fahrbach's answer shows. There is some problem with your question.

Comment: What could be the correct problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

Something seems incorrect here (and it may be my understanding of the problem and counterexample). Counterexample: Suppose that the only friend of $a_1$ is $a_2$, the only friend of $a_2$ is $a_1$, the only friend of $a_3$ is $a_4$, the only friend of $a_4$ is $a_3$, etc.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i=100$ because each student has only one friend. However, $\sum_{j=0}^{99}c_j = c_0 + c_1 + \dots c_{99} = 100 + 100 + 0 + \dots + 0 = 200$.

Maybe we are trying to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i = \sum_{j=1}^{99}c_j$ instead.

Comment: No, the problem statement had j=0. Maybe it was wrong, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Define a graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$ on the vertices $V=\{1,\dots,100\}$, with $\{i,j\}\in E$ if and only if $i$ and $j$ are friends. The number $a_i$ is the valency of the vertex $i$, a well-known fact, known as [the degree sum formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29) states
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} a_k=2|E|.$$
Using your definition of $c_j$ try to argue that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{99}c_j=2|E|$.

Comment: Can you suggest a combinatorial method?

Comment: It doesn't get more combinatorial than this. What is the context of the question? What tools are you thinking of using?

Comment: You have used graph theory which I don't know. This problem came in my exam today. Can you suggest any other method?

Comment: What is the subject of the exam? What did you learn about this subject? How do you solve questions of this kind?

Comment: The exam is called ISI Entrance Exam. The syllabi for this exam is 10+2 mathematics. I haven't solved a question like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i = \sum_{j=1}^{99} c_j.
$$

Here is "visual explanation":

[image]

Shortly, it is based on rearrangement of summation.

Let there is sequence $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_n$ of nonnegative integer numbers. 
Denote $A=\max\limits_{1\le i \le n} a_i$.
Then one can write
$$
a_i = \sum_{\Large{1\le j \le A,}\atop\Large{ j\le a_i}} 1; \qquad (i=1,2,\ldots,n);
$$

$$
c_j = \sum_{\Large{1\le i \le n,}\atop\Large{ a_i\ge j}} 1; \qquad (j=1,2,\ldots,A);
$$

then

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i 
\qquad = \qquad \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{\Large{1\le j \le A,}\atop\Large{ j\le a_i}} 1
\qquad = \qquad \sum_{j=1}^A \sum_{\Large{1\le i \le n,}\atop\Large{ a_i\ge j}} 1 
\quad = \qquad \sum_{j=1}^A c_j.
$$